# Docky Keeps Crashing 13.04

Tags: 13.04, docky, crash

The title kind of explains itself.  Docky will just randomly crash.  It will ask If I would like to restart or keep closed, If I try and restart, it wont.  Its becoming frustrating as I prefer Docky over Launcher.  Anyone have a fix for this?  BTW I'm a Ubuntu noob.... Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is to be reported as BUG not an answer. use this command to generate and report bugs.

apport docky. that will collect and inform launchpad about docky.

ps: my docky also crashes very often but at that time I.will use report bug button in the crash window.

How :
Just open your terminal and type as

ubuntu-bug docky

then you will get a windows like [image]

that will collect all the information about your application and with positive actions you can report it to launchpad.

for debugging program crash , I mean if you would like to trace yourself why its behaving like that you can read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash

Comment: Ok sorry.  I'm still getting used to these forums. What command should I use?

Comment: @Colper answer updated